# скажите знатоки, что с этим кодом не так, не даёт ожидаемый результат

Tags: python

```
bonuses={'950895778':['1234','12000'], '912045858':{'1255':13000}, '911458384':{'7896':14000},
 '999987311':{'1111':15000},
   '975950701':{'2222':15000}}

bot=Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp=Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', ])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Hi enter your phone number")
    
    
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_send(message:types.Message):
    if message.text in bonuses.keys():
        text=bonuses[message.text]
        await message.answer("Your discount card number")

@dp.message_handler()
async def score_send(message:types.Message):
    if message.text in text[0]:
        await message.answer(f"Your score:{text[1]}")
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

скажите пож что здесь ни так. спасибо.

[image: Ожидаемый результат]

Answer (score 0):

Хоть я и не эксперт, но разве 2 функции с одинаковым @ не будут мешать друг другу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из очевидного:
text - локальная переменная, ты не можешь к ней так обращаться. Даже если сможешь, при использовании 2мя+ юзерами у тебя все сломается.
Обрати внимание, что в словаре у тебя в первом слоте очки в формате строки.

Comment: "не будут мешать друг другу?" ошибки не будет. Короче кто первый тому и тапки.

Comment: Как получить ожидаемый результат, уважаемые, что добавит/что удалить, спс

Comment: или же можно 1 хендлером обойтись?

Comment: Используйте FSM